# Flipping 180 degree a UI element used as button, result in the click not intercepted

Tags: unity-game-engine

While rotating an element used as button, I did notice that it won't intercept anymore click events from the mouse.

I can even hover on it, and it won't change color, it act like if it was a simple image. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What axis are you rotating the UI? Are rotating the canvas or just the component?Also what's the screen mode of the canvas?

Comment: I did rotate 180 on Y axis; I just rotated the button (using an arrow image, so the most logic thing to flip the arrow in the other direction was to rotate it). The screen mode of the canvas is Screen space - Overlay. Scaler is set to scale with screen size and match width or height

Comment: Have you checked that it has raycast hit checked and that there is no element above it with it checked. If there is any change you moved rotated any other object, that could have gone in front of it, even if it's a child.

Comment: Yes, the same button when not rotated 180 degree, works just fine. There is no element above it, I can reproduce the issue just with a blank canvas and one single button on it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Canvas > Graphics Raycaster > Uncheck Ignore Reverse Graphics` then the image can be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Flip it via the Z rotation (not the X or the Y). I tested it on my end, it works.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue and found a way to fix it. If you flip the button over the x axis as well as the y you still get the button facing the direction you want but the click will register.